# Clicking notification behavior only works when the app is in the background in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification

I am trying to push notification to all users subscribed to custom topic using firebase cloud functions , but in background notification scenario when clicking notification it navigates to the desired screen only when the app is in the background , but when killing the app and there is a notification it opens the home screen not a notification topic

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', // id
    'High Importance Notifications', // title
    'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
    importance: Importance.high,
    playSound: true);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('A bg message just showed up :  ${message.messageId}');
}

void subscribeToTopic() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('notifications');
    print('subscribed to topic');
  } catch (e) {
    print('error is $e');
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscribeToTopic();

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessage data is ${message.data}');
      print('onMessage notification is ${message.notification}');

      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
              ),
            ));
      }
    });

 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
    
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/productsScreen');
    
    });
    
  }

  void showNotification() async {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        "Testing $_counter",
        "How you doin ?",
        NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id, channel.name, channel.description,
                importance: Importance.high,
                color: Colors.blue,
                playSound: true,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher')));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: showNotification,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FirebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage()` after your app opens from a terminated (killed) state. See the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/getInitialMessage.html)

The `FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp` only works when app is in the background state but still running. So at the end of the day, your main would simply look like this:

```
RemoteMessage? initialMessage;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // We add this additional line to get the initial message
  initialMessage =  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

If the `initialMessage` is not null, you will know that the user clicked on the notification and the app has opened right after that. After this you can process the data inside the initialMessage as you wish, preferably after calling `runApp()` since you want to navigate to a different screen after user opens the app.